# How do I add a bundle to a theme?

Tags: xpages

How can I include a bundle e.g.

```
<xp:bundle src="/strings.properties" var="strings"></xp:bundle>
```

in a Theme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can clip off the `xp:` part and put it in a `<resources/>` block in a theme, like most resources, but I actually advise against it. As much as I love putting as much as I can in a theme, doing so means that you can't access the bundle at load time. Since the theme is only applied during rendering, any binding like `<xp:text value="${strings.foo}"/>` will end up blank.